# How to report percentages by rows in createtableone command in tableone package?

Tags: r, row, percentage

I want to report percentage by rows using CreateTableOne from tableone package in r using the following code

```
vars<-c( "Group1vsGroup2", "Single.Institution",  
           "Internal.Funding",  "National.Funding", 
           "Industr1.Funding")

CatVar<-c(  "Single.Institution",  
           "Internal.Funding",  "National.Funding", 
           "Industr1.Funding")


tab2 <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, strata = "Group1vsGroup2",factorVars = CatVar,data = df,test = T);tab2<-print(tab2, margin=1,test = T, varLabels = T,quote = T,dropEqual = T)
```

I added "margin=1" as I saw in this [website](https://rdrr.io/github/dewittpe/qwraps/man/tableone.html) although it was for tableone command (not CreateTableOne), but I got % by columns as in the image below. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I don't think `CreateTableOne` has an argument to manage the direction. Maybe you should try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Descriptives.html, you may need to do an extra typing but you will get great flexibility from `Gmisc` and `htmlTable`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying Gmisc now but could not identify the proper command for that though. I went through Gmisc documentation but couldn't allocate it yet. Any input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a MWE you can start with, see `?Gmisc::getDescriptionStatsBy` for more details.

```
library(Gmisc)
# Define cyl as a factor so that getDescriptionStatsBy can use the correct Gmisc::describe*
mtcars$cyl=as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
getTable1Stats <- function(x, digits = 0,...){
  getDescriptionStatsBy(x = x, 
                        by = mtcars$am,
                        digits = digits,
                        header_count = TRUE,
                        ...)
}

t1 <- list()
t1[["Gas"]] <- getTable1Stats(mtcars$mpg, add_total_col="last")
#hrzl_prop=FALSE will indicate that the proportions are to be interpreted in a vertical manner
t1[["Cylinder&dagger;"]] <- getTable1Stats(mtcars$cyl, hrzl_prop=TRUE, add_total_col="last")
t1[["Disp"]] <- getTable1Stats(mtcars$disp, continuous_fn=describeMedian, add_total_col="last")

mergeDesc(t1,
  htmlTable_args = list(css.rgroup = "",
  caption  = "Basic descriptive statistics from the mtcars dataset",
  tfoot = "&dagger; The weight is in 10<sup>3</sup> kg")
)
```

[image]

PS: This solution based on Max's vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Gmisc/vignettes/Descriptives.html). For more details on `htmlTable` you can see its vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html)

Comment: Great. Thank you so much. In the last column, could we put 100% in each  cell?

Comment: I don't think so as this last column should represent how many cars have Cyl=4, 6, and 8. But if you want to do so, you can modify the table/output before sending it to `mergeDesc`. Here is an example `cyl <- getTable1Stats(mtcars$cyl, hrzl_prop=TRUE, add_total_col="last");cyl[,3] <- c("11 (100%)", "7 (100%)", "14 (100%)" );t1[["Cylinder&dagger;"]]<-cyl`

Comment: Sorry, is there any way to report 1 decimal place in percent as I  noticed that it reports % without any decimal places ?

Comment: @MohamedRahouma just changes the variable `digits` in _getTable1Stats_ which is default to 0 i.e. no decimal. You can change `digits` when you define the function or when you call it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Is there anyway to report certain level as I have some variables coded as 0 and 1 and I need to know only level 1 in the table?