# How to summarise by group AND get a summary of the overall dataset using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate summaries for different groups AND simultaneously calculate a summary for the overall (ungrouped) dataset, preferably using dplyr (or something that fits well into a dplyr pipeline).

The desired result can be achieved by separately calculating group summaries, then the overall summary, and then joining the results. However this seems a bit inefficient I am hoping there is a simpler solution that requires less duplication of code. I didn't find anything that related to this in the documentation or from other questions.

Reproducible data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(500)
dat <- 
    data_frame(treatment = sample(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
               recruitment_strategy = sample(c("Strategy 1", "Strategy 2", "Strategy 3", "Strategy 4", "Strategy 5"), 100, replace = TRUE),
               Variable_A = rnorm(100),
               Variable_B = rnorm(100),
               Variable_C = rnorm(100))
```

Code to calculate means of several variables by group AND the means from the overall dataset:

```
count_by_group <- dat %>% 
    group_by(treatment) %>% 
    count(recruitment_strategy) %>%
    mutate(`n (%)` = paste0(n, " (", round(n / sum(n)*100,0), "%)")) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    spread(treatment, `n (%)`)

count_overall <- dat %>% 
    count(recruitment_strategy) %>%
    mutate(`n (%)` = paste0(n, " (", round(n / sum(n)*100,0), "%)")) %>%
    select(-n) %>%
    rename(Overall_dataset = `n (%)`)

left_join(count_by_group, count_overall)
```

The desired output is achieved with the above code: a table of means for each group, next to overall means:

```
  variable   Group1  Group2  Group3 Overall_dataset
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Variable_A -0.154  0.0385  0.263           0.0351
2 Variable_B  0.212 -0.232  -0.124          -0.0671
3 Variable_C -0.195  0.194   0.0508          0.0376
```

A similar process on a categorical varaible to get counts and percentages for each group, and for the overall dataset:

```
count_by_group <- dat %>% 
    group_by(treatment) %>% 
    count(recruitment_strategy) %>%
    mutate(`n (%)` = paste0(n, " (", round(n / sum(n)*100,0), "%)")) %>% # calculate percentage in the desired format for table
    select(-n) %>%
    spread(treatment, `n (%)`)

count_overall <- dat %>% 
    count(recruitment_strategy) %>%
    mutate(`n (%)` = paste0(n, " (", round(n / sum(n)*100,0), "%)")) %>% # calculate percentage in the desired format for table
    select(-n) %>%
    rename(Overall_dataset = `n (%)`)

left_join(count_by_group, count_overall)
```

```
  recruitment_strategy Group1  Group2   Group3  Overall_dataset
  <chr>                <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>          
1 Strategy 1           2 (6%)  13 (30%) 4 (16%) 19 (19%)       
2 Strategy 2           8 (26%) 6 (14%)  6 (24%) 20 (20%)       
3 Strategy 3           6 (19%) 12 (27%) 3 (12%) 21 (21%)       
4 Strategy 4           9 (29%) 4 (9%)   5 (20%) 18 (18%)       
5 Strategy 5           6 (19%) 9 (20%)  7 (28%) 22 (22%)
```

Is there a solution that can get a grouped summary AND an overall summary in a single step, rather than requiring the assignment of two separate objects that are then joined into a third object?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739156/how-to-report-percentages-by-rows-in-createtableone-command-in-tableone-package/57740386#57740386

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would rewrite your code.

There is a trick with pipes to use the `.` to put the LHS in multiple places on the RHS. That lets you do the join without needing to assign the intermediate objects. I also used a few more steps for a different balance of clarity vs not repeating myself, such as doing all the grouping inside `count()` and using its `name` argument, using `mutate_at` to do all the formatting after the join, and using `str_glue` and `scales::percent` to make the string formatting a little more readable.

All of this is a matter of preference to some degree, but I think avoiding the intermediate assignments (and the burden of having to name said objects) is solved by the below approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(500)
dat <- tibble(
  treatment = sample(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  recruitment_strategy = sample(c("Strategy 1", "Strategy 2", "Strategy 3", "Strategy 4", "Strategy 5"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Variable_A = rnorm(100),
  Variable_B = rnorm(100),
  Variable_C = rnorm(100)
)

dat %>%
  inner_join(
      x = count(., treatment, recruitment_strategy) %>% spread(treatment, n),
      y = count(., recruitment_strategy, name = "Overall_dataset"),
      by = "recruitment_strategy"
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(-recruitment_strategy),
    .funs = ~ str_glue("{.} ({scales::percent(. / sum(.), accuracy = 1)})")
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   recruitment_strategy Group1  Group2   Group3  Overall_dataset
#>   <chr>                <glue>  <glue>   <glue>  <glue>         
#> 1 Strategy 1           2 (6%)  13 (30%) 4 (16%) 19 (19%)       
#> 2 Strategy 2           8 (26%) 6 (14%)  6 (24%) 20 (20%)       
#> 3 Strategy 3           6 (19%) 12 (27%) 3 (12%) 21 (21%)       
#> 4 Strategy 4           9 (29%) 4 (9%)   5 (20%) 18 (18%)       
#> 5 Strategy 5           6 (19%) 9 (20%)  7 (28%) 22 (22%)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Really useful answer Calum - have a new question related to this here if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947171/how-to-summarise-by-group-and-total-with-missing-counts-using-dplyr